# django with django-pyodbc not create any table by syncdb on SQL Server 2008

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I met a strange issue that no any table created on SQL Server 2008 after successfully execute django syncdb operation.

here is the console output:

```
    Creating tables ...
    Creating table django_admin_log
    Creating table auth_permission
    Creating table auth_group_permissions
    Creating table auth_group
    Creating table auth_user_groups
    Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
    Creating table auth_user
    Creating table django_content_type
    Creating table django_session

    You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
    Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): yes
    Username (leave blank to use 'xxx'): admin
    Email address: xxx@gmail.com
    Password: admin
    Password (again): admin
    Superuser created successfully.
    Installing custom SQL ...
    Installing indexes ...
    Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
    Finished "E:\Users\xxx\Documents\Eclipse Workspace\PyDev\chaos\manage.py syncdb" execution.
```

here is my settings.py for django:

```
    # SQL Server 2008
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django_pyodbc',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'NAME': 'Chaos',
            'USER': 'chaos',
            'PASSWORD': 'admin',
            'OPTIONS': {
                'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 10.0',
                'MARS_Connection': True,
            },
        }
    }
```

pls help to figure out the root cause. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue these day.

then I found this https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc/issues/38

> Django 1.6 now assumes that autocommit defaults to True, meaning that it must explicitly be set to work with 1.6 (eg, syncdb will appear to succeed but not create any tables).

the solution is add 'autocommit': True, to OPTIONS, like this:

```
    # SQL Server 2008
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_pyodbc',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'NAME': 'Chaos',
        'USER': 'chaos',
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 10.0',
            'autocommit': True,
            'MARS_Connection': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. autocommit is the root cause.